# How to get clean urls in yii2 like ``post/100``

Tags: .htaccess, url, nginx, routes, yii2

I am quoting the guide:

Depending on the urlManager configuration, the created URL may look like one of the following (or other format). And if the created URL is requested later, it will still be parsed back into the original route and query parameter value.

```
/index.php?r=post/view&id=100  
/index.php/post/100  
/posts/100
```

I am interested in third option or second without index.php. But how can I get it ? 
I have .htaccess that is removing index.php ( I may need something for nginx, but do not know what and how, I have never used it).
And I have pretty url set:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

what is next ?

I have asked [the same question](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61028-how-to-get-clean-urls/) on yii2 forum, but I got no answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in `.htaccess` or `Nginx` for this purposes.

`index.php` already removed with that setting:

```
'showScriptName' => false,
```

Pretty urls are already enabled with that line:

```
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
```

That means urls like `?r=post/view` won't be generated.

The only thing left is to configure `rules`.

If we have `PostController` and its action `view` and `id` as primary key, second option without `index.php` will be:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
         'post/<id:\d+>' => 'post/view',
    ],
],
```

For the third option just add `s` in the left section of rule:

```
'posts/<id:\d+>' => 'post/view',
```

The official documentation covers that [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules).

Comment: @arogachev You have mentioned a great answer above.I also need a small help on the rules.I have used a template under web/theme/demo(name of the theme), i want remove web/index.php and putting only basic i should get the home page, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove /web prefix you need to point your webserver to this subdirectory instead of the project root