# How to write friendly URL using Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new in yii2, and I'm trying to create Pretty URL's but its not been succesfull yet.
Using `yii2-advance`, I have set `frontend/config/main.php` like:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true
],
```

Now, I access url in my browser: 
`localhost/myapp/frontend/web/site/post?id=1` [OK]
`localhost/myapp/frontend/web/site/post/id/1` [404]

What is wrong? I would like the URL as:
`localhost/myapp/frontend/web/<title>/<id>`
and what should I do?
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get clean urls in yii2 like \`\`post/100\`\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944703/how-to-get-clean-urls-in-yii2-like-post-100)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the rules of array just like following

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
   ],
```

Considering that you have already created a `.htaccess` file inside your project and added necessary code in it